# Issues with Laravel Scout using TNTSearch driver

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-artisan, laravel-scout

I'm getting the error message:

> 'Driver [tntsearch] not supported'

With Laravel Scout when I issue the Artisan command 
`php artisan scout:import "App\Location"`

```
php artisan -V => Laravel Framework 5.4.16
```

Is anyone else seeing this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install TNTSearch Engine for Laravel Scout:

```
composer require teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver
```

Add the service provider:

```
// config/app.php
'providers' => [
    // ...
    TeamTNT\Scout\TNTSearchScoutServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Load vendor config

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider"
```

Add `SCOUT_DRIVER=tntsearch` to your `.env` file
In your `config/scout.php` add:

```
'tntsearch' => [
    'storage'  => storage_path(), //place where the index files will be stored
    'fuzziness' => env('TNTSEARCH_FUZZINESS', false),
    'fuzzy' => [
        'prefix_length' => 2,
        'max_expansions' => 50,
        'distance' => 2
    ],
    'asYouType' => false,
],
```

Comment: Obviously taking text directly from TNT's github installation instructions isn't the answer I was looking for since I offered my laravel version.

php artisan -V => Laravel Framework 5.4.16

It apperas that scout only support laravel 5.3.  I'm interested if anyone has figured a work around for tnt in 5.4

Comment: It works for me in Laravel 5.4.*. Have you updated the package?